# How to import as 'components/filename' instead of '../../../components/filename' in React JS/Next JS + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to import my pages, components, and containers directly like `'components/filename'` OR `'@components/filename'` instead of specifying the path to the parent folder like `'../../components/filename'`

How can I achieve that in React JS or Next JS with Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from next.js docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases
here is the example from project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to check the .jsconfig of your project, follow this article to learn about it : https://dev.to/rfornal/create-path-aliases-in-react-2oid

also check this article : https://medium.com/hackernoon/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4c6cfb66c35d